# Issue with JavaScript position/ordering in MVC application

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, location

perhaps this question may already asked. But I have not find satisfactory answer for below scenario.

I have MVC application, in which, when I click on button it popup a jquery dialog. It works fine if I include jquery***.js  in header. But it is not working if I include after Body.

According to best practices, we should include all scripts after body. So, why this dialog does not open when I include script at bottom.

```
**Layout.cshtml**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @Content.Css("themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css", Url)
    @Content.Css("Site.css", Url)

    /**** Dialog works fine if I include 
    *** @Content.Script("jquery-1.5.1.min.js", Url) ***
    ***here*****/

</head>
<body>

   *********
   *********

    @Content.Script("jquery-1.5.1.min.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js", Url)
    @Content.Script("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", Url)
</body>
</html>


Index.cshtml

@model ****

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            model: true
        });
    });

    function btn1Click() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm () )
{
    <input id="btn1" value="Index1" type="button" onclick="btn1Click()"  /> 
    <br />

        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>Testing...</p>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: You are attempting to use jQuery when it has not yet been loaded. Browsers parse the code as it appears. Put jQuery on top or, at least, before you actually use it.

Comment: Ok. So, I cant place jquery***.js at bottom in above scenario. It means, there are some exception with best practices (Put Scripts at the Bottom - http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). Thank you.

Comment: You actually should compile all your javascript into one file. Read about `Minify JavaScript and CSS` on the same document

Comment: interesting... thanks for your suggestion. I am going to use Minify JavaScript and CSS in my project.